# How to find group-column have duplicate values in a dataframegroup python?

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, pandas-groupby

first i have a df, when i groupby it with a column, will it remove duplicate values?.
Second, how to know which group have duplicate values ( i tried to find how to know which columns of a df have duplicate values but couldn't find anything, they just talk about how each element duplicated or not)

```
ex i have a df like this:
     A    B   C
1    1    2   3
2    1    4   3
3    2    2   2
4    2    3   4
5    2    2   3

after groupby('A')

A    B       C
1    2       3
     4       3
2    2       2
     3       2
     2       3
```

i want to know how many group A have B duplicated, and how many group A have C duplicated

```
result:
   B    C
1  1    2

or maybe better can caculate percent

B : 50%
C : 100%
```

thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could use a lambda function inside [`GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.aggregate.html) to compare number of unique values that is not equal to the number of values in a group. To get the number of unique we can use [`Series.nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.nunique.html) and [`Series.size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.size.html#pandas.Series.size) for the number of values in a group.

```
df.groupby(level=0).agg(lambda x: x.size!=x.nunique())

#        B      C
# 1  False   True
# 2   True  False
```

Answer (score 2):

Let us try

```
out = df.groupby(level=0).agg(lambda x : x.duplicated().any())
       B      C
1  False   True
2   True  False
```

Comment: thank you sir, first i want to ask what do `level=0` do?, then it seem run slow with my data ( 191600 row and 300 if i group them ). Second i have edited my question, can you help me?